# phpmysql dump not working if password has "(" or ")" or "&"

Tags: php, mysql, exec

I am trying to do a mysql dump and I am having issues when the database password has either "(" or ")" or "&" in it. There may be more but till now I have tested with these characters.
My script is:

```
$un = "user_name_here";
$pass = "gTbK5AQ)iuT";
$hn = "localhost";
$dbn = "database_name_here";
$exp = "export_path_here";
$output = array();
exec("mysqldump --user=$un --password=$pass --host=$hn $dbn > $exp", $output, $worked);
```

The script does not work if the $pass has ")" in it. When I remove ")" from the password then the dump works fine and exports the database in sql format as I want. 
Is there any mistake I am doing or the password should not have these characters?

Comment: No. But think about what those characters placed in a command line would do if you entered them from the command line. The shell is doing something with those characters

Comment: Quote the password value: `exec("mysqldump --user=$un --password=\"$pass\" --host=$hn $dbn > $exp", $output, $worked);`

Comment: Just put the entire command in single quotes

Comment: Just put **password** into single quotes

Comment: @MarkBaker, I will give that a try and let you know in a moment if that worked or not. Thank You so much.

Comment: Just be careful if the password contains quotes, because then you'll need to escape the quotes as well

Comment: @MarkBaker, that worked like a charm. Thank You so much, you saved my day! If you post this as an answer I would love to accept that as correct anwser. Thank you Man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your password contains characters that can be misinterpreted by your shell as control sequences, then you need to wrap the value in quotes to ensure that they are treated as literals

```
exec("mysqldump --user=$un --password=\"$pass\" --host=$hn $dbn > $exp", $output, $worked);
```

Note that if your password contains literal quotes, then you'll need to escape them as well